# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\Admin::notify()

Tags: laravel

My `notify()` method is `undefined` and I get this error. I use Laravel 8 and I am trying to have the Admin get a notification when a Participant checks in.

##### Admin Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Accommodate;
use App\Models\Admin as ModelsAdmin;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\Participant;
use App\Notifications\ParticipantCheckIn;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class Admin extends Controller
{
    //
    use Notifiable;
    
    public function loginpage()
    {

        return view('Admin/adminlogin');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data
        $credentials =  $request->validate([
            'National_id' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);

        // Retrieve the adminicipant based on the National_id
        $admin = ModelsAdmin::where('National_id', $credentials['National_id'])->first();

        if ($admin) {
            // Authenticate the adminicipant
            Auth::guard('admin')->login($admin);
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        } else {
            // adminicipant not found
            return redirect('adminlogin')->withErrors([
                'National_id' => 'Invalid National ID or Passport',
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function AdmDashboard()
    {

        return view('Admin/dashboard');
    }

    public function Checkins(){
        if(auth()->guard('participant')->user()){
            $part = Participant::first();
    
            $course = Course::where('National_id', $part->National_id)->get();
            $admin = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
    
            $url = route('checkins'); // Replace with the actual route for the checkins page
    
            $admin->notify($admin, new ParticipantCheckIn($part, $course, $url));
        }
    
        return view('Admin/allocate', ['part'=>$part, 'course'=>$course, 'admin'=>$admin]);
    }

    public function allocate(Request $request)
    {
        $admin = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
        $acc = new Accommodate();
        $acc->Course_id = $admin->Course_id;
        $acc->Participant_id = $request->Participant_id;
        $acc->Admin_id = $request->Admin_id;
        $acc->hostel = $request->hostel;
        $acc->room_no = $request->room_no;
        $acc->save();
        return redirect('adminlogin');
    }
}
```

##### Admin Dashboard

```html
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    You're registered!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@if (session('status'))
<script type="text/javascript">
    iziToast.show({
        title: 'Hey',
        message: "{{ session('status') }}",
        position: 'topCenter'
    });
</script>
@endif
</x-app-layout>
```

##### The App layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'AccommodationRegistration') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::to('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/izitoast@1.4.0/dist/css/iziToast.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/izitoast@1.4.0/dist/js/iziToast.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        @include('layouts.navigation')

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <header class="bg-white shadow">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                {{ $header }}
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <main>
            {{ $slot }}
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

##### The navigation layout

```html
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
    <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
            <div class="flex">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="shrink-0 flex items-center">
                    <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
                        <x-application-logo class="block h-10 w-auto fill-current text-gray-600" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Navigation Links -->
                <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-nav-link :href="url('admin/dashboard')" :active="request()->url('admin/dashboard')">
                        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
                    </x-nav-link>
                    <x-nav-link :href="url('admin/Checkins')" :active="request()->url('admin/Checkins')">
                        {{ __('Check in Participants') }}
                    </x-nav-link>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Settings Dropdown -->
            <div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ml-6">
                <x-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">
                        <button class="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                            <div>{{ auth()->guard('admin')->user()->Full_Names }}</div>

                            <div class="ml-1">
                                <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="content">
                        <!-- Authentication -->
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                this.closest('form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Log Out') }}
                            </x-dropdown-link>
                        </form>
                    </x-slot>
                </x-dropdown>
            </div>

            <!-- Hamburger -->
            <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                <button @click="open = ! open" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path :class="{'hidden': open, 'inline-flex': ! open }" class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                        <path :class="{'hidden': ! open, 'inline-flex': open }" class="hidden" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
    <div :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': ! open}" class="hidden sm:hidden">
        <div class="pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
            <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                {{ __('Dashboard') }}
            </x-responsive-nav-link>
        </div>

        <!-- Responsive Settings Options -->
        <div class="pt-4 pb-1 border-t border-gray-200">
            <div class="px-4">
                <div class="font-medium text-base text-gray-800">{{ auth()->guard('admin')->user()->Full_Names }}</div>
                <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ auth()->guard('admin')->user()->email }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-3 space-y-1">
                <!-- Authentication -->
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('logout')"
                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                        this.closest('form').submit();">
                        {{ __('Log Out') }}
                    </x-responsive-nav-link>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

##### `auth.php` (routes)

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Participant;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {

    #Personal Details routes
    Route::get('participant/register', [Participant::class, 'retrieve'])
        ->name('register');
    Route::post('participant/register', [Participant::class, 'proceed']);

    #Confirm ID routes
    Route::get('participant/register/page2', [Participant::class, 'confirmpage']);
    Route::post('participant/register/page2', [Participant::class, 'confirm'])->name('confirm');

    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('password.request');

    Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('password.email');

    Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('password.reset');

    Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('password.update');
});

Route::middleware('participant')->group(function () {

    #Course Details routes
    Route::get('participant/register/page3', [Participant::class, 'course']);
    Route::post('participant/register/page3', [Participant::class, 'submit_c'])->name('course');

    #Work_Profile routes
    Route::get('participant/register/page4', [Participant::class, 'work_profile'])->name('work');
    Route::post('participant/register/page4', [Participant::class, 'submit_wp']);

    #Hospital Details routes
    Route::get('participant/register/page5', [Participant::class, 'med_details'])->name('med');
    Route::post('participant/register/page5', [Participant::class, 'submit_md']);

    #NOK routes
    Route::get('participant/register/page6', [Participant::class, 'kin'])->name('kin');
    Route::post('participant/register/page6', [Participant::class, 'submit_kin']);

    #Dashboard routes
    Route::get('participant/dashboard', [Participant::class, 'viewDashboard'])->name('check_in');
    Route::post('participant/dashboard', [Participant::class, 'check_in']);

    #Dashboard routes
    Route::get('participant/dashboard/wait', [Participant::class, 'waitarea']);
});

Route::middleware('participant')->group(function () {

    #Admin Login routes
    Route::get('admin/Login', [Admin::class, 'loginpage'])->name('adm');
    Route::post('admin/Login', [Admin::class, 'login']);

    #Admin Dashboard routes
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', [Admin::class, 'AdmDashboard']);

    #Admin Checkin routes
    Route::get('admin/Checkins', [Admin::class, 'Checkins'])->name('checkins');
    Route::get('admin/confirmCheckIn', [Admin::class, 'allocate']);

    #Admin Checkout routes
    Route::get('admin/Checkouts', [Admin::class, 'Checkouts']);
    Route::get('admin/confirmCheckout', [Admin::class, 'checkoutby']);
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('verify-email', [EmailVerificationPromptController::class, '__invoke'])
        ->name('verification.notice');

    Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
        ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
        ->name('verification.verify');

    Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
        ->name('verification.send');

    Route::get('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
        ->name('password.confirm');

    Route::post('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store']);

    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('logout');
});
```

I tried using `Notification::send()` and I get this error:

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method `App\Models\Admin::routeNotificationFor()`.